# How do I get the "Standard" timezone string from a moment object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am working on an asp.net project, doing various things handling dates and times between a database on the server and widgets that display them on the client. I am trying to use moment.js.

When I debug my moment object I see the following information:

[image: SampleData]

I need to use the "Pacific Daylight Time" portion, as that is the only string format accepted by the TimeZoneInfo c# class (which I am using on the backend).

**How do I get that piece of data?**

I've read through the docs and guides and there is nothing related to the "Standard" names of timezones, only city-based ones like "America/Los Angeles", which is unsuitable. I *could* make a dictionary mapping the city names to the standard names, but that would take quite a while and be a pain, so I would like to find the proper way to do this.

Comment: These zones are problematic if you are starting with only a date. For example, 14:49 GMT-077 is 7:49 Pacific Daylight Time, but it is also 7:49 in Arizona where they are observing Mountain Standard Time. Given a UTC timestamp, how can you know Pacific Daylight is the correct zone?

Comment: As Mark Meyer points out, there are some issues to be aware if you do not include the city. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/499#issuecomment-305338182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use string parsing, or a C# library

I found 2 solutions that got me the data I needed, but both are pretty awful and hacky.

1. On the front end, call the moment's `.toString()` function and pattern match the result to get just the timezone name.

This can be done with regex or `.split()` and it works, assuming that the format of the date string never changes. It can look like:

```
var timeZoneName = momentDate._d.toString().split("(")[1].split(")")[0];
//timeZoneName now holds "Pacific Daylight Time"
```

After passing that value to the back end you still need to replace "Daylight" with "Standard" to create a TimeZoneInfo instance.

2. On the back end, use an external library to do the mapping for you.

The two libraries I found were [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) and [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter). These can take IANA-style names and match them to their Windows Standard equivalents. I used TimeZoneConverter like:

```
localTZName = TZConvert.IanaToWindows(tzName);
TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localTZName);
```

The tzName was the result of using `moment.tz.guess()` on the front end. This method worked very well but it is the pre-built equivalent of making a map from 1 style to the other, so I'm glad someone else went through that pain so I didn't have to.

### Both of these solutions are terrible, but there doesn't seem to be a way around them

The first solution relies on the hope that the string representation of the moment never changes, and moment really should have a way to get this particular piece of data without having to cut it out of a string, especially since *they already go through the trouble of finding the data*, they just don't let you have it.

The second solution is just a brute force mapping. Inelegant, ugly, but it works, although it really feels like it should be something native to either moment.tz.js or TimeZoneInfo, or preferably both.

The disconnect seems to come from the fact that moment.js refuses to acknowledge that Windows exists, while Windows refuses to acknowledge that timezones are complicated beasts with lots of history that can effect accurate dating.